# Django model foreign key on_delete=null but foreign key is deleted anyway

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to change a foreign key reference's on delete value from cascade to null like so:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

When I test this by deleting a record from CustomUser I get a count of the objects in the Games table before and after performing the delete.

```
p = Games.objects.count()
print(p) #outputs 100
print(Games.objects.filter(created_by=2)) #outputs <QuerySet [<Games: 181 79 None>]>

cu = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=2)
cu.delete()

p = Games.objects.count()
print(p) #outputs 98
print(Games.objects.filter(created_by=2)) # outputs <QuerySet []>
```

I have tried using the other values for on delete but the only one that doesn't delete the rows from the database is protect. It instead raises a protection error

```
 raise ProtectedError(
django.db.models.deletion.ProtectedError: ("Cannot delete some instances of model 'CustomUser' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'Games.created_by'", <QuerySet [<Games: 181 79 None>]>)
```

Code for CustomUser and Games models

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email



class Games(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('general knowledge','general knowledge'),
        ('science','science'),
        ('mythology','mythology'),
        ('sports','sports'),
        ('geography','geography'),
        ('history','history'),
        ('politics','politics'),
        ('art','art'),
        ('celebrities','celebrities'),
        ('animals','animals'),
        ('vehicles','vehicles'),
        ('entertainment','entertainment'),
        ('random','random')
    )

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    number_of_questions = models.SmallIntegerField()
    number_of_players = models.SmallIntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=CATEGORY)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    result_id = models.ForeignKey(Results, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sudden_death_id = models.ForeignKey(SuddenDeath, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.id, self.result_id, self.sudden_death_id)
```

Comment: what is your Django Version?

Comment: @LucasWieloch 3.0.7

Comment: foreign key argument with `models.SET_NULL` is correct. You sure your migrations are up to date?

Comment: @LucasWieloch Yes, I just double checked and my migrations are up to date

Comment: Well, I would hint then for you to test it by getting the game pks connected to `cu` before deleting it, and after deleting do `Games.objects.filter(pk__in=game_pks)` to make sure that the records are still there. Other than that, I suggest you to post an example with a bigger code snippet because whatever the error is it might be outside of the scope of the blocks in your question

Comment: @LucasWieloch I've tried that and it just confirms that the records are being deleted. I have updated the original question with code snippets for both models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `django-extensions` `reset_db` to reset my database, deleted all of my migrations and re-ran. `makemigrations` & `migrate` After importing the same datasets from my fixtures i ran this block of code again

```
        p = Games.objects.count()
        print(p) #output 100
        print(Games.objects.filter(created_by=2)) # output <QuerySet [<Games: 181 79 None>]>
        cu = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=2)
        cu.delete()
        p = Games.objects.count()
        print(p) #output 100
        print(Games.objects.get(pk=181)) #output 181 79 None
```

Which confirms that the foreign key row was not deleted.

I'm marking this as the accepted answer, but if someone is able to explain how to resolve the question without resetting the database I'll mark that as the accepted answer instead.